# Getting "undefined" error in defined prop in React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is really strange because as you can see in screen shot below, I can actually see the value of what the debugger is claiming to be `undefined`.

The actual error message is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined

[image]

I put a break point and verified that the `application` prop as well as the `applicant` and `firstName` properties are defined and can see their values.

Any idea what may be causing this?

Comment: this could be because on initial render that `application.applicant` prop is not available

Comment: @HarishSoni Right on the money!!!! Thank you!